# White box appears under the like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When testing the like button on my page - I notice once pressed it shows a white box under it (where photos should be - although i have diabled that function).  It can be removed by refreshing the page but i find this unsightly and covers vital content from the page.

Is there a way of stoping this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely relates to this known issue: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/293075054049400.